# How to get PUBG user account info by player id through API

Tags: node.js, reactjs, api

Our team is going to make a website which provides services of pubg. As you can see this website : `https://www.midasbuy.com/in/buy/pubgm#`. so **Is there any pubg api for mobile exists ? That takes pubg profile id (Player's Id) and returns the user info (Player account info) as name etc.** Profile Id sample is attached. [Image added for profile Id](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iW8wH.jpg)

I already checked the pubg developer portal for api's. But didn't get any result.

Answer (score 1):

PUBG-Mobile data is currently not available via PUBG API!

But PC, XBOX ONE and PS4 APIs are available.
You just need to get an API key from PUBG-Developers.

See [that](https://medium.com/@rpicapstone1/how-to-write-a-pubg-app-using-the-free-pubg-api-4d625729ebac) for more info.

Just found something, maybe it helps: [API](https://developer.toornament.com/v2/core-concepts/disciplines/pubg_mobile)

Comment: Is there ANY other way to get PUBG-Mobile data?